# Exporting data from App Engine via Objectify in the form of SQL statements to build a SQLite database

Tags: android, sql, google-app-engine, sqlite, objectify

I am using Objectify to store data on Google App Engine.  I want to put my data into SQL format so I can use it in an android project.  Is it possible to go from Objectify to SQL?  Is there a library I could use, or will I have to do it manually?

Comment: This seems like a non-sequitir: What does SQL have to do with Android? Also, there's no such thing as "SQL format" - and how are you going to get your data from App Engine to your Android app?

Comment: What sthompso wants to do (from RL discussions) is build up a data store in App Engine, then copy a representation of it to an Android app so the app can access the data locally.  I suggested she create a servlet within App Engine that provides the SQL statements to regenerate the database (e.g., "CREATE TABLE foo(...); INSERT INTO foo ...; ...").  The SQL statements can then be used to create a SQLite database on the development machine or on the phone, which can be queried from the app.  Is that any clearer?

Answer (score 2):

Having your App Engine app send SQL statements to your Android app probably isn't a good idea. It requires your App Engine app to have unnecessary knowledge about the inner workings of your Android app; it forces your Android app to continue using an SQL database with the specified schema for the indefinite future, and it makes it difficult or impossible to write another client for another platform that uses a different datastore.

There's also potential security implications - if your App Engine app was compromised, or you communicate over an insecure connection, an attacker could make arbitrary changes to the Android app's datastore.

Instead, have your App Engine app output data in a common format such as JSON or XML, then have your Android app read the data and perform operations such as inserting data into the datastore based on it.